# Protecting the breakout pins

Tags: gpio

I want to use the pins of the Raspberry Pi B+ but knowing that I may destroy it by accident, for example by extreme current, I want to ask if there is a way to be sure that this will never happen. Is there any module I can buy or build which will ensure that my Raspberry will always be protected?

Comment: Anything you could find to protect your Pi is likely to cost more than the Pi.  It's probably best to take care when attaching anything to the pins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buffering of digital inputs/outputs by buffer ICs (e.g. the SN74HC244N) could offer a *certain* level of protection at reasonable cost. It however might limit your future design choices as the direction of the pin (input or output) will be fixed according to the wiring. Bidirectional voltage level translator (e.g. the [TXS0108E](http://www.ti.com/product/TXS0108E)) will overcome this limitation and needs no Direction-Control signal.

Since all those solution do not offer galvanic isolation they can offer only limited protection. Things as mains level voltages or even relays driven without appropriate drivers and fly-back diodes might kill the buffer and the Pi too. However, "always" protection and being flexible in the use of the GPIO pins is most likely more expensive than the Pi itself (just as joan's comment suggested). The buffers will protect from thing that are somewhat likely to happen though: "minor" over-voltage (e.g. connecting to 5V) and ESD issues to a certain degree.

Here are some projects/products that employ buffering:

- https://www.hackster.io/DaddyDoug/raspberry-pi-buffered-i-o-209748
- http://www.briandorey.com/post/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Protection

  - this solution does not work with SPI and the author suggests using CD74HC4050 instead (per [GuZzie's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57321/protecting-the-breakout-pins/57322?noredirect=1#comment187736_57322), thanks)
- http://thebox.myzen.co.uk/Raspberry/Buffer_Board.html

Comment: For future references if someone else uses this. After speaking to brian dorey (2nd link) he confirmed his solution does not work with SPI and suggested using CD74HC4050 instead

Comment: @GuZzie thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

The only pins you really need to be concerned about insulating are the power pins.  There are four of them on the B+, two are 5V and the other two are 3.3V (you can readily find them on a B+ GPIO schematic).

The simplest way to protect these pins from accidental grounding or shorting to an adjacent GPIO pin is to cover them with an empty female dupont connector.  You can buy a package of these little plastic connectors on eBay, or just cut off the end of a GPIO jumper cable and use it to cover the power pin.

When you need to connect something to the power pin, simply remove the dupont housing cover and put it aside.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be worrying too much. I have incorrectly connected GPIO lines lots of times and so far I haven't damaged a Pi. But to avoid accidental connections I use female to female dupont cables on the pins I'm going to work with and then use a male-to-male connector to make the final connection to the protoboard. This makes it easier to connect and disconnect without shorting things by accident.

Comment: I don't think encouraging people to not worry if they misconnect things is very good, lol.  I still haven't wrecked one either but I take every mistake I notice as a lesson in what corners not to cut when fiddling (and as you say, that comes down to how you are tending the connections).

Comment: You obviously haven't encounter the users too frightened to try anything for fear that they will destroy the device. In fact it can be even worse. I've seen people draw back in fear when the switch it on in case it spits fire.

Answer (score 1):

Because of I=E/R  (Ohm's Law), the simple and cheap way to achieve current limitation is a simple and cheap resistor hooked up in series with the GPIO pin as a current limiting resistor.

In R=E/I, put the max amount of current desired from the GPIO pin (16ma) as the I term (current in amperes), the voltage on the GPIO pin as the E term (3.3V for a RPi2 GPIO pin) and the R component will be the value of the resistor needed.

For the above? 127+ ohms or nearest upper equiv (150ohms etc) for 3.3v/.016amp.